# Python: txt into dictionary. Split() TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, dictionary

I just started with Python and I'm having some troubles with one exercise. I am really sorry if the question is too "basic stuff" but I've done my research on google and can't find any short and not too complicated answer. And now the exercise:

"Write a program that reads the words in words.txt and stores them as keys in a dictionary. It doesn't matter what the values are. Then you can use the in operator as a fast way to check whether a string is in the dictionary."

I tried this:

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/MissOgra/Documents")
fname = input("File name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "words.txt"
fh= open(fname)
counter = 0
dictionairy = dict()
for line in fh:
    word = line.rstrip()
    dictionairy[word] = counter
    counter += 1
    print(dictionairy)
```

However, I don't get the words, but sentences. So I thought I could use `split()` like this:

```
import os
os.chdir("/Users/MissOgra/Documents")
fname = input("File name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "words.txt"
fh= open(fname)
counter = 0
dictionairy = dict()
for line in fh:
    word = line.rstrip().split()
    dictionairy[word] = counter
    counter += 1
    print(dictionairy)
```

But now it doesn't work. I get:

```
dictionairy[word] = counter
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Can anyone please explain to me why is that happening and give me a hint about how can I fix it? Please, pretty please?

Comment: Hint: print `word` before you use it; it's not what you think it is.

Comment: [```split```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) returns a list which is mutable and cannot be *hashed*.  [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) keys must be [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) - that is why you are getting an error.  Print statements/functions can really help when you have these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using `str.split()` you would get a list of the split words, you would need to iterate over that list and set it to the dictionary. Example -

```
for line in fh:
    words = line.rstrip().split()
    for word in words:
        dictionairy[word] = counter
        counter += 1
```

Comment: Thanks :) it helped me a lot!